# Access TFS field TC Description

Tags: c#, tfs

[image]

I want to get the values of Description of test cases in TFS as shown in the image using C#. let me know if anyone knows how to get this using C#.

Comment: I think anyone will know it, so the answer to your question is "yes". If you want to know **how** to do it, that your question is far too broad. What *exactly* is your problem? What did you try allready? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @HimBromBeere I don't have any idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below sample to get the value of Description of a specific test case:

With Nuget package [Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/) intalled

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client;
using System;

namespace RetrieveTestCaseDescription
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var u = new Uri("http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection");
            var c = new VssClientCredentials();
            int TestCaseId = 57; 
            TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(u, c);
            tpc.EnsureAuthenticated();

            ITestManagementService test_service = (ITestManagementService)tpc.GetService(typeof(ITestManagementService));
            ITestManagementTeamProject project = test_service.GetTeamProject("ProjectNameHere");
            ITestCase testcase = project.TestCases.Find(TestCaseId);
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} - {1}", testcase.Id, testcase.Description));
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]